# How to count the total ABCDE in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a C program that could read the students' scores until the user enter end of file (EOF) and determine whether their grade is A, B, C, D, or E. I'm having troubles in counting the total of A's, B's, C's, D's, and E's. The total is always 0 (zero).

This is what I've tried

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

int num_stu, score, counter, total,grade;
int aCount = 0, bCount=0, cCount=0,
    dCount=0, eCount=0;

total = 0;
counter = 1;

printf("Enter how many number of students: ");
scanf("%d",&num_stu);
while (counter <=num_stu){
    printf("Enter student score: ");
    scanf("%d",&score);
if(score>=80)
    printf("Student's grade is A\n");
else
if(score>=70)
    printf("Student's grade is B\n");
else
if(score>=60)
    printf("Student's grade is C\n");
else
if(score>=50)
    printf("Student's grade is D\n");
else
    printf("Student's grade is E\n");

counter=counter+1;
}

while ((grade=getchar()) !=EOF) {

 switch (grade){

 case 'A':case'a':
 ++aCount;
 break;

 case'B': case'b':
 ++bCount;
 break;

 case'C': case'c':
 +cCount;
 break;

 case'D':case'd':
 ++dCount;
 break;

 case'E':case'e':
 ++eCount;
 break;

 case'\n': case' ':
 break;

 default:
 printf("Incorrect letter grade entered.");
 printf("Enter a new grade.\n");
 break;
}
}
printf("\n Totals for each letter grade are: \n");
printf("A: %d\n",aCount);
printf("B: %d\n",bCount);
printf("C: %d\n",cCount);
printf("D: %d\n",dCount);
printf("E: %d\n",eCount);

return 0; }
```

Is there anything that I did wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you account for the `'\n'` left in `stdin` generated by the user pressing **[Enter]** after `(grade=getchar()) !=EOF` ? Suggest `char grade[128];` and then `while (fgets (grade, sizeof grade, stdin)) { switch (*grade) ... }`

Comment: Note: dereferencing the array `grade` (e.g. `*grade`) simply returns the 1st character, the remainder of the line, including the `'\n'` are simply ignored, but you consume an entire line of input with each call to `fgets()` (provided you size you array with sufficient storage -- lesson: don't skimp on array size...).

Comment: Here you are asking user to provide value for "num_stu" and obtaining marks for only those no. of students whereas in question you have written that : read the students' scores until the user enter end of file (EOF) , both are different, please clarify on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of `'\n'` every time you press enter. So to get rid of these Put
one `getchar()` before the while loop and one get char inside the while loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int num_stu, score, counter, total,grade;
    int aCount = 0, bCount=0, cCount=0,
        dCount=0, eCount=0;

    total = 0;
    counter = 1;

    printf("Enter how many number of students: ");
    scanf("%d",&num_stu);
    while (counter <=num_stu){
            printf("Enter student score: ");
            scanf("%d",&score);
        if(score>=80)
            printf("Student's grade is A\n");
        else
        if(score>=70)
            printf("Student's grade is B\n");
        else
        if(score>=60)
            printf("Student's grade is C\n");
        else
        if(score>=50)
            printf("Student's grade is D\n");
        else
            printf("Student's grade is E\n");

        counter=counter+1;
    }

        getchar();
    while ((grade=getchar()) !=EOF) {
        getchar();

        switch (grade){

            case 'A':case'a':
            ++aCount;
            break;

            case'B': case'b':
            ++bCount;
            break;

            case'C': case'c':
            +cCount;
            break;

            case'D':case'd':
            ++dCount;
            break;

            case'E':case'e':
            ++eCount;
            break;

            case'\n': case' ':
            break;

            default:
            printf("Incorrect letter grade entered.");
            printf("Enter a new grade.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
        printf("\nTotals for each letter grade are: \n");
        printf("A: %d\n",aCount);
        printf("B: %d\n",bCount);
        printf("C: %d\n",cCount);
        printf("D: %d\n",dCount);
        printf("E: %d\n",eCount);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Perhaps simplify `case`s with `switch (grade){` --> `switch (toupper(grade)) {`?  (Tip: use an auto for matter to improve code appearance).